# Can't change Font Awesome icon on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to change a font awesome icon using a toggle, however, nothing seems to be working and i am not sure why?

(HTML)

```
<span class="change-icon"><i class="far fa-eye" id="password-see"></i></span></div>
```

(CSS)

```
.change-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

(Javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('change-icon').click(function () {
        $('i').toggleClass('far fa-eye far fa-eye-slash');
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why, in your JS, you use `far` class 3 times?

Comment: Oh apologies, thats a typo in the question - i've eddited it now (the issue still persists)

Comment: Try this $('i').toggleClass('fa-eye fa-eye-slash')

Comment: @StevenPss still no luck unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to get the html element .change-icon but you try to get it with $('change-icon') instead of $('.change-icon') where the dot is representing that it is a class

Change this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('change-icon').click(function () {
        $('i').toggleClass('far fa-eye far fa-eye-slash');
    });
});
```

To this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.change-icon').click(function () {
        $('i').toggleClass('fa-eye fa-eye-slash');
    });
});
```

And i would change $('i') to $('#password-see')

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk i also checked, you do not need the double "far".

If this awnser helped you could you accept it please?

Comment: Yes, i've removed the double far now as well. And accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.change-icon').click(function () {
        $('i').toggleClass('fa-eye fa-eye-slash');
    });
});
```

Comment: Does still not work, look at my awnser, you also try to get the object with $('change-icon') instead of getting it by class with $('.change-icon') please look at the jquery documentation

Comment: You are correct @LorenzoOtto, I was focused on the toggleClass section and copied / pasted from his code. I will edit my answer now. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.change-icon').click(function (event) {
            $(event).find('i').toggleClass('far fa-eye far fa-eye-slash');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: also, $(event) aswell as the double far is not needed.